# Iterate over a vector of pairs and access first and second element

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, std-pair

I am trying to iterate over a vector of pairs and access first and second elements.

I cannot use auto, so I need to use the iterator.

```
  for (list<string>::const_iterator it = dest.begin(); it != dest.end(); ++it)
  {
    for (vector< pair < string, string > >::iterator it2 = class1.begin(); it2 = class1.end(); ++it2)
    {
      if (it == it2.first)
        cout << it2.second;
    }
  }
```

I keep getting errors:

> Has no member named first.

I have tried: it2->first, it2.first and (*it2).first.

Why is it not working?

Comment: Even though this is trivial, for future issues, always include error messages. When all a poster says is "this doesn't work" it's much harder for us to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare an iterator to a string. This isn't only about the syntax to dereference `it2`, you also have to dereference `it`. The proper syntax is

```
if (*it == it2->first)
```

By the way you've made a typo, you've written `it2 = class1.end()` instead of `it2 != class1.end()`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if (it == it2.first)
```

to this:

```
if (*it == it2->first)
```

since `it` iterates over a vector of string, so you need to dereference it to take the actual string. Similarly for `it2`, where instead of using `*` and `.`. together, you use `->` for easiness.